# Configuring log4j grails

Tags: grails, logging, log4j, config

I'm new in grails and I need to configuring loggind for my application. I started to configure log4j in my grails application and I got this error described below and I don't know what makes this:

```
log4j:ERROR Property missing when configuring log4j: Environment
```

Someone know what causes it? Below is my code!

```
def myappLogLevel = "DEBUG"
def myappLogPattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd/HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %x %-5p %c{2} - 
%m%n"
def log4jFileName = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base', '.') + 
"/logs/myapp.log"

environments {
    development {
       log4jFileName = "logs/myapp.log"
    }
test {
    log4jFileName = "logs/myapp.log"
}


log4j = {

def logLayoutPattern = new PatternLayout(myappLogPattern)

appenders {
    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(name: "myappLog",
            threshold: Level.toLevel(myappLogLevel),
            file: log4jFileName,
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",   //Rollover at midnight each day.
            layout: logLayoutPattern
    )
    if (Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT ||
            Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
        appender new ConsoleAppender(name: "console",
                threshold: Level.toLevel(myappLogLevel),
                layout: logLayoutPattern
        )
    }
}
error 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',  //  controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', //  GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', //  layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate.cache',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
'grails'
'groovyx.net.http'

warn 'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'grails.plugins.springsecurity',
        'groovyx.net.http'

debug 'grails.plugins.springsecurity',
        'grails.plugin.springcache',
        'com.myapp',
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity',
        'org.apache.http.headers',
        'grails.app.services',
        'grails.app.domain',
        'grails.app.controllers',
        'grails.plugin.databasemigration',
        'liquibase'

    List<String> loggers = []
    loggers.add('myappLog')
    if (Environment.current.name == "development" ||
        Environment.current.name == "test") {
          loggers.add('console')
    }
    root {
        error loggers as String[]
        additivity = true 
    }

}
```

Comment: You'll need to import grails.util.Environment to have Environment available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use the log config DSL construction to branch on environment without explicitly accessing Environment.

```
environments {
    development { loggers.add('console') }
    test { loggers.add('console') }
}
```

That said, I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the rest of the configuration, so there may be a more elegant way to handle things.